# Initialization through XML of autopropery with private setter in Autofac

Tags: xml, private, autofac, setter

I'm using some Autofac modules to initialize config files. E.g.:

```
public class Config()
{
  public String ConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

Regarding XML configuration everything looks like:

```
 <Autofac defaultAssembly="Autofac">
   <components>
     <component type="Autofac.Configuration.Config, Autofac" instance-scope="single-instance" >
       <properties>
         <property name="ConnectionString" value="Cnstring" />
       </properties>
     </component>
   </components>
 </Autofac>
```

I'm using this configuration to have Configuration, but in order to make it immutable I use a private setter `{get; private set;}`.
 This doesn't works in Autofac, can you please advise how should use private setter initialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Peter's answer, if you want to stay with property and property injection, you can add "immutability" manually by code, something like that:

```
public class Config
{
    private string _connectionString;

    public String ConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            return _connectionString;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_connectionString != null) throw new ReadOnlyException("_connectionString");
            if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("value");

            _connectionString = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, I definitely can, but this way value isn't populated by Autofac.

Comment: @Johnny_D Why? It has public setter.

Comment: Oh, my misjudjement. Sorry, indeed you solution suits my question better. However I've managed to encaplsulate logics for readonly on one level higher that configuration file. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the property is read-only, Autofac will not be able to initialize it via property injection. You should use constructor injection instead in this case.